# How to default one panel open in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am sorry about how simple this question might be, but I cannot find the information I am looking for.  I have two divs on my page and they are controlled by some jQuery that will open and close them.  When the page loads they are both defaulted to close.  I was wondering how I would make one default to open (loginDiv) when the page loads or does a post back?  I am very novice at jQuery and the person that helped me this far is not an option right now.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

    (function($) {
        var containers = ['login', 'account'];

        var toggle = function(container, flag) {
            span = $('#' + container + 'Link').find('span');
            div = $('#' + container + 'Div');

            div[flag ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
            span.html(flag ? '-' : '+');
        };

        var clickHandler = function() {
            container = this.id.match(/^[a-z]*/);
            flag = $(this).find('span').html() == '+';
            toggle(container, flag);

            if (flag) {
                for (i = 0, j = containers.length; i < j; i++) {
                    con = containers[i];


                    if (con != container)
                        toggle(con, 0);
                }
            }
        };

        $(function() { // on load

            for (i = 0, j = containers.length; i < j; i++)
                $('#' + containers[i] + 'Link').click(clickHandler);

        });

    })(jQuery);

    //]]>
</script>

//And here are the divs:
<div id="loginDiv" style="display:none">...</div>
<div id="accountDiv" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

I tried changing the display on the loginDiv to anything but none, and it still does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/Em64X/

Basically the page intializes with the elements not displayed. When the page loads (thats the `$function(){` bit) we set the login elements css value `'display'` as block. and bam - we have a visible element on page load.

I also included a quick little toggle button there for displaying only one at a time. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do there but it looks like you're trying to find all one one element - add a click event to it to do stuff. This one just does a slide toggle on anything with the class 'hideAble' which both or divs there do have.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Added changing of span's text on load.

Comment: Close!  Thanks, but now the only problem is the "+Login" stays shows on page load where it should be "-Login" when that div (the one I want open by default) is open.  All this is, since you asked, is a page with a "Login" or "Create Account" form and each form is in its own div, being opened and closed by the jQuery clicks.  I have them automatically close when the other gets open, so thats fine, but if I can have one be open when someone navigates to that page that would be great.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't really get this functionality the first round. Please update you're HTML to reflect the children spans inside the divs (at least I'm assuming thats where they are). I updated the example to change the first spans content.

Comment: Actually, what you had earlier helped me get it.  I had to do some more research, but you helped point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do your `<div>` tags purposefully not have closing `</div>` tags? Make sure you close those and try removing the `display:none` from the `loginDiv`.

Comment: Normally you should comment, but since you don't have that much reputation, I will do that on your behalf and then you can delete this answer, OK?

Comment: Goodness, I am sorry!  Yes, the div tags do close, I just forgot to put that in the code.  I will edit that now.  Also, I tried your suggestion already as well, but the "+Login" stays where it should be "-Login" when that div is open.  That's why I was wondering if there is a way to set the default open/close through the jQuery.